# How to upgrade angular material MatPaginator to version 8

Tags: angular, angular-material

Ive recently upgraded my project including angular material to version 8. However, there are a few issues which i'm not sure how to fix.

**component.ts**

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
```

**component.html**

```
   <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

            <!-- Class Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="class">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Class </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.class}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Topic Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="topic">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Topic </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.topic}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Tme Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="datetime">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Date & Time </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.time | date:'medium'}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="show(row)"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>


        <mat-paginator #paginator [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" [showFirstLastButtons]="true">
        </mat-paginator>
```

The above ViewChild is now expecting 2 arguments. https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration

I'm not sure how to update these as they were taken from the angular material version 7 documentation.

The new version documentation does not have these ViewChilds. https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/examples

I don't see a angular material 8 migration guide.

Comment: Have you updated using the `ng update` command? It runs schematics over your code to automatically fix and migrate code that is prone to change. The `ViewChild` was definitely one of the automated upgrades to be ran. You can run the `migration only` version: `ng update @angular/core --from 7 --to 8 --migrate-only`

Comment: Yes i also read that it should have done it automatically, ive already done the ng update command, it did not change this for me,

Comment: Well all the automatic updated examples I saw were turned in `@ViewChild(MatExample, { static: false })`. So I hope that answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's remember that we need to change the paradigm while updating Angular and its libraries from direct `npm` manipulation to use the `ng update` schematics.

If you update didn't finished correctly and you don't have version control to undo the changes and try again, you can execute:

`ng update @angular/core --migrate-only --from 7 --to 8`

That will re-execute the update schematic in your project. I had to do this updating `@angular/materia`l because I had too many files to change that the script ran out of memory :P

Happy ng-coding!

Answer (score 0):

Fix

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator , {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/25188863)

Answer (score 0):

As Luiz suggested, Adding `{static: true}` as the extra parameter solves this. Setting it like this will ensure query matches that are dependent on binding resolution (like structural directives `*ngIf, etc...`) will be found.

`{ static: false }` will be accessible only in `ngAfterViewInit`. This is also what you want to go for when you have a structural directive (`*ngIf` etc.) on your template.

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator , {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;
```